# How to print columns with awk and in the same time edit just one column?

Tags: command-line, bash, files, text-processing, awk

Still on beginner level!

**Example** of one line in my `file.txt`:

```
158.45.456.756 - - [04/Feb/2016:10:51:24 -0500] "GET /tiles/1.0.0/cd/base/1/85/785.png?wb75678545=75D2503E HTTP/1.1" 200 8848 "http://site/map.html" "Mozilla/5.0 (Windows NT 6.1; MOM64; Trident/7.0; mv:10.0) like Blah"
```

**Result** I want **to accomplish**:

```
[04/Feb/2016:10:51:24-0500]/tiles/1.0.0/cd/base/1/85/7852008848
```

---

**What I have tried until now**

`awk '{ print $4 $5 $7 $9 $10}'` will return:

```
[04/Feb/2016:10:51:24-0500]/tiles/1.0.0/cd/base/1/85/785.png?wb75678545=75D2503E2008848
```

which is not good because this part `.png?wb75678545=75D2503E` shouldnt be  contained in the line.

I also tried just printing 7th column and delete everything after last point with `awk '{ print $7}' | grep -Po '.*(?=\.)'` which returned me result that I want for specific column:

```
/tiles/1.0.0/cd/base/1/85/785
```

however I end up being left out with other part of the line.

---

**Question**

How can I print all the columns I need and in the same time or before edit just 7th column?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

With `awk`:

```
awk '{print $4 $5 gensub("(.*/[^.]+)\\..*", "\\1", 1, $7) $9 $10}'
```

- `print` prints the required fields without any modification, with only the required portion of the 7th field being extracted with `gensub()`
- In `gensub("(.*/[^.]+)\\..*", "\\1", 1, $7)`, the Regex pattern `"(.*/[^.]+)\\..*"` matches the portion prior to the `.` after last `/`, and put that in captured group `1`, and then the rest as matches by `\\..*`. In the replacement only the captured group is used to get that portion only
- In Regex pattern `(.*/[^.]+)\\..*`, the portion inside the captured group `()` i.e. in `.*/[^.]+`, `.*/` matches greedily upto the last `/`, then `[^.]+` matches the portion upto the next `.`, this is kept as captured group 1 as this is our desired portion, and we will use the group in replacement, then `\\.` matches a literal `.`, then `.*` matches the rest of the string

From comment, if you want to keep `.` inside the match i.e. want `.` too:

```
awk '{print $4 $5 gensub("(.*/[^.]+\\.).*", "\\1", 1, $7) $9 $10}'
```

**Example:**

```
% awk '{print $4 $5 gensub("(.*/[^.]+)\\..*", "\\1", 1, $7) $9 $10}' <<<'158.45.456.756 - - [04/Feb/2016:10:51:24 -0500] "GET /tiles/1.0.0/cd/base/1/85/785.png?wb75678545=75D2503E HTTP/1.1" 200 8848 "http://site/map.html" "Mozilla/5.0 (Windows NT 6.1; MOM64; Trident/7.0; mv:10.0) like Blah"'
[04/Feb/2016:10:51:24-0500]/tiles/1.0.0/cd/base/1/85/7852008848

% awk '{print $4 $5 gensub("(.*/[^.]+\\.).*", "\\1", 1, $7) $9 $10}' <<<'158.45.456.756 - - [04/Feb/2016:10:51:24 -0500] "GET /tiles/1.0.0/cd/base/1/85/785.png?wb75678545=75D2503E HTTP/1.1" 200 8848 "http://site/map.html" "Mozilla/5.0 (Windows NT 6.1; MOM64; Trident/7.0; mv:10.0) like Blah"'
[04/Feb/2016:10:51:24-0500]/tiles/1.0.0/cd/base/1/85/785.2008848
```

Comment: thanks for a quick reply. still cant conform does the whole file work because I am having some other difficulties. Can you please explain what does the  "(.*/[^.]+)\\..*", "\\1", 1, stands for? How could you be able to delete everything after the point, but leave the point in the line.

Comment: @vayacondios2015 Check my edits.

Comment: Thanks for explanation and additional answer! Later on I kind of realized that I need to include a dot also!